# On clone of html row with text box the trigger for the new textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a duplicate row on click the duplicate row is the last row of that html table but the problem is that on newle created row the text box is not triggers as the class is same as is for original but on keypress the numeric function which adds comma and checks alphabets not happening

[Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/kQpfE/266/)

html:

```
<table id='tbl'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>cell</p>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input name="txtMSExMarCardFee2" type="text"   class="Stylednumber">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add New Row"></button>
```

JS

```
$("#btnAdd").on("click",function(){

var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone();

    $trLast.after($trNew);
});

  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};



$('input.Stylednumber').keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val().replaceAll(',', '');
  if (input.length < 1)
    $(this).val('0.00');
  else {
    var val = parseFloat(input);
    var formatted = inrFormat(input);
    if (formatted.indexOf('.') > 0) {
      var split = formatted.split('.');
      formatted = split[0] + '.' + split[1].substring(0, 2);
    }
    $(this).val(formatted);
  }
});

function inrFormat(val) {
  var x = val;
  x = x.toString();
  var afterPoint = '';
  if (x.indexOf('.') > 0)
    afterPoint = x.substring(x.indexOf('.'), x.length);
  x = Math.floor(x);
  x = x.toString();
  var lastThree = x.substring(x.length - 3);
  var otherNumbers = x.substring(0, x.length - 3);
  if (otherNumbers != '')
    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
  var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree + afterPoint;
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input.Stylednumber').keyup` function binds event to elements that are currently in dom. If you want to bind an event to dynamically created elements, you must specify global scope like `body` or in this situation it can be `table#tbl`.

```
$('table#tbl').on('keyup', 'input.Stylednumber', function(){ ... });
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kQpfE/268/

Comment: absolutely correct but can the newly created row s text box's value be 0.00 insted of the previous values ones thanks for the support

Comment: All you need to do is  `$trNew.find('input').val('0.00');` before inserting it.